# kdb - checking dictionary variables for data vs. lambdas

Tags: kdb

All,
I have numerous nested dictionaries that I've been building and updating on the fly which can be combination of variables and lambdas functions. My initial inputs are constants and incremental data varies but are mostly derivatives using lambdas and function references.

I keep running a type issues as I pass constants and lambdas into my functions and my functions break. The solution at present is to simply wrap all my constants and data as simple f(x)s but I'd like to handle that inside my functions instead of wrapping everything.

In my example below, I'd like to add a conditional or something to QAQC the variable so I can handle it inside each function.

`.inv.1.startDate: 2022.10.10`  is a constant then my function breaks at `` sd: d[`startDate][] ``  (which make sense as its not a function) but will work if `.inv.1.startDate: {2022.10.10}`

I tried a conditional below but it fails as not all dictionary values are f(x) either.
`` sd: ?[(type d[`startDate]=100h;d[`startDate][];d[`startDate])] ; `` which doesn't seem to work either.

Example of incremental references to render an array of  series of dates

```
.inv.1.startDate:2022.10.10; //<---- works as f(x) but not when a constant
.inv.1.duration: 155;
.inv.1.iDate:{dateArray[.inv;1]};

.inv.2.startDate: {last (.inv.1.iDate[])};
.inv.2.duration: 250;
.inv.2.iDate:{dateArray[.inv;2]};

.inv.3.startDate: {last (.inv.2.iDate[])};
.inv.3.duration: 95;
.inv.3.iDate:{dateArray[.inv;3]};

dateArray:{[seg;segNum];
  d: seg[`$string segNum];
  sd: d[`startDate][];     //this can be a constant or a f(x) depending on when its called)
  days: d[`duration];      // this could be a constant or a f(x) as well
  
  result: sd+ til days             
  };

//attempt to emply a conditional but fails due to data type
sd: ?[(type d[`startDate]=100h;d[`startDate][];d[`startDate])] ;
```

FWIW- this is an expansion upon
[kdb - nested functions within nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911843/kdb-nested-functions-within-nested-dictionaries)

Comment: Thanks Terry on the cleanup.

Comment: What's wrong with using `{2022.10.10}` as a lambda? That to me is the cleanest solution and the one I would use

Comment: Nothing really - just coordinating with front end dev to aid in data mapping. We have to put the variables in a wrapper so I was just attempting to reduce add'l code.

Comment: Terry, is there a clever bit of code to iterate through a dictionary and convert all variables to functions?  I'm playing with your code below and found a link to your response here im testing: ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53783853/kdb-getting-error-when-i-wrap-working-code-in-a-function```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to wrap your processing in a try-catch:

```
sd:{@[x;`;x]}d`startDate;
```

but as I mentioned in an earlier comment, personally I think it would be cleaner to have the constants in a lambda, e.g. `.inv.1.startDate:{2022.10.10}`

Comment: Thanks Terry - I'm working with my front end dev and we were revisiting the topic.  We have been running with the lambdas methodology as you recommended just trying to minimize having to have a wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using `?` in cases where `$` is more applicable https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cond/

Also there is an order of evaluation issue with:

```
type d[`startDate]=100h
```

https://code.kx.com/q4m3/4_Operators/#412-left-of-right-evaluation

What you want is:

```
(type d[`startDate])=100h
```

Or more cleanly:

```
100h = type d[`startDate]
```

Comment: Thanks rianoc, I swapped out the conditional but it still fails. The issue seems to be the type error value and function in side  dateArray function.  The conditional throws a type error when I swap out the .inv.1.startDate from a function {2022.10.10} to a constant 2022.10.10.  Again, my solution is to wrap all the input data into simple f(x) but looking for options to validate this in my dateArray f(x)

Comment: I've added to my answer - you have an order of evaluation issue in your code.